# How do I avoid duplicated code in Css using Scss?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to avoid the same code in all css files to keep the app as fast as possible? For example, the heading in every page comes from a headings.scss file and that means that the code for the heading is in every css file. And if the css files are going into a one page, that code will be duplicated multiple times if I´m not manually deleting the lines one by one.

Is there a way to avoid this?

**Update:**
I have one css file for every html file and that css is mapped from a  sass file. The sass files use global styling like headings.scss, buttons.scss etc. When the css files are created, every file has those five lines of styling for a button, which means that if I have a button in every page (say 20), there will be 20 blocks of the exact same code in a project.

Now a developer is using my code and he created a onepage for html and one for css. When he imports the css files into one, the button code will be 100 lines (20 duplicates). Is this just the way it has to be without spending time to manually delete 19 blocks or is it a better/standard/smart way to do this? Without changing everything I´ve done so far and keep the organized file structure?

Comment: _“and that means that the code for the heading is in every css file”_ - what do you mean by “every” CSS file here? Why do you have _multiple_ of those to begin with? You need to _properly_ explain what kind of setup you are using there exactly.

Comment: If you have a generic part of SCSS just make sure to generate a generic CSS file from it as well which you use on all pages instead of including that part into every page-specific SCSS file and therefore duplicating it in the output.

Comment: _“I have one css file for every html file”_ - why? _“Now a developer is using my code and he created a onepage for html and one for css.”_ - if the desired end result was a one-page all along - then why did you develop this in a completely different structure to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry about that, I added some more information now. I´m new to using sass. He didn´t know how to construct the project until recently and wanted me to begin  doing html/css for him to use.

Comment: @rauberdaniel I have several generic SCSS files (buttons, variables, headings, mixins etc) that the .scss for every html page use, do you know a better way I can do this? Like creating one generic file? Without spending loads of time changing everything?

Answer (score 0):

i just can show you what i generally do and how i do structure it

1 - I have all my scss file being imported once in to a **main scss** file

```
src -> scss -> bundle.scss

// 1.1 - base
@import "./base/vars";
@import "./base/reset";
@import "./base/structure";
@import "./base/header";
@import "./base/footer";

// 1.2 - navs
@import './components/primary_nav_header';
@import './components/primary_nav_sidebar';

// 1.3 - templates
@import "./templates/home";
@import "./templates/products";
@import "./templates/products-single";
@import "./templates/search-results";
@import "./templates/contact";

// 1.4 - components
@import "./components/buttons";
@import "./components/hamburgers";
@import "./components/hero";
@import "./components/cards";
@import "./components/breadcrumb";
```

2 - And then all this will be compiled into a tyni single **main css minified** file in

```
dist -> css -> bundle.css
```

3 - then just import it

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='./dist/css/bundle.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: That looks great! I have the same structure but every html page has its own scss (and mapped to a css that is included to the html page), and at the top of every scss i import main.scss. My main also imports the different scss components.


To clarify: my start.html has link to start-style.css, the start-style.css is mapped from start-style.scss. At the top of start-style.scss I import main that has button and component  styles and also the specific style to that page. Where do you import the specific css to each html file? Do you import that bundle.css to every html page?

Comment: Or do you import the bundle once and don´t have that "import main" at the top of the page scss? Then the button style won´t be added in the start-style.css but it will be added later when bundle is imported?